# Find all folders in a directory with the same content

Tags: shell-script, directory, file-comparison

In Ubuntu, is there any to find duplicate folders in a directory (i. e., folders with the same content)? I think there are already some command-line tools available for finding duplicate files (such as fdupes), but I want to find duplicate folders instead.  That is, find folders which match in terms of the contents of the files they contain (though the filenames and other metadata might differ).

Comment: I might start by generating a list of all folders in a directory (sorted by length), and then check each pair of folders with the same length.

Comment: Define "duplicate". Must the files inside match merely file content? File name? Inode number? File size?

Comment: @ChrisDown The question has been updated.

Comment: I don't see any clarification of what it means to be a duplicate directory...

Comment: @ChrisDown I said "folders in a directory with the same content" - does this need further clarification? Two "duplicate folders" would contain the same files and folders in the same order.

Comment: Yes. Directories are really just files, so your statement is ambiguous. To have the "same content" in reality would mean that the directories both contain the same inode references. It is unclear whether you mean that, or whether you mean that the *files inside* should have the same content, and if so, whether there are other stipulations (mtime, filename, etc).

Comment: @ChrisDown I mean that the files inside should have the same content.

Comment: So, to be clear, all other metadata other than the file content is irrelevant?

Comment: @ChrisDown Yes, all metadata other than the file content would be irrelevant.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6711/discussion-between-anderson-green-and-chris-down)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s dotglob

for file in "$1"/*; do [[ -f "$file" ]] && d1+=( "$(md5sum < "$file")" ); done
for file in "$2"/*; do [[ -f "$file" ]] && d2+=( "$(md5sum < "$file")" ); done 

[[ "$(sort <<< "${d1[*]}")" == "$(sort <<< "${d2[*]}")" ]] && echo "Same" || echo "Different"
```

You can see it in action here:

```
$ mkdir 1 2
$ ./comparedirs 1 2
Same
$ cat > 1/1 <<< foo
$ cat > 2/1 <<< foo
$ ./comparedirs 1 2
Same
$ cat > 2/1 <<< bar
$ ./comparedirs 1 2
Different
```

Comment: Since this script is untested, I'm eager to see whether it works the way it's supposed to work.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Check the updated answer, tested it.

Comment: Nice!  There should also be a test with `cat > 1/2 <<< bar` and `cat > 2/3 <<< bar`  to show multiple files and differing metadata (== "Same")

Comment: @ChrisDown: does sort in last step needed?

Comment: Elegant script, only minor bug is that it returns Same when either or both directories do not exists. Should be easily fixable if one is better in scripting than I.

Comment: @AndersonGreen why do you accept this answer? You asked to _find all folders in a directory with the same content_, not just compare two given folders.