# Detect duplicate folders with identical content

Tags: duplicate-files

I often have folders with different names but the same content.

For example, I copy a folder to another location, for ease of access, and then I forget to delete the copy.

How can I detect the duplicate folders, with the same content?

For detecting duplicate files, I use Czkawka, but did not find a similar tool for duplicate folders.

Similar questions:

detect duplicate folders but ignoring the presence of empty folders
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43560796/how-to-find-duplicate-directories

detect duplicate folders but the folder name matters
[Find and list duplicate directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288591/find-and-list-duplicate-directories)

Comment: *For example, I copy a folder to another location, for ease of access, and then I forget to delete the copy.* Have you heard about symbolic links? You can make them with `ln -s`, and they are awesome.

Comment: When you consider a folder (directory) do you want to just the files directly in it, or any files that are in subdirectories too?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, thanks. The example is an example: I made it up for being concise and help to understand.

Comment: @roaima I think that including the subdirectories you can have a more useful and well-defined tool.

Comment: Do you want to detect duplicate folders (per your question), or verify whether or not two known named folders are duplicates?

Comment: @roaima finding duplicates. For checking if two defined folders are duplicates, I would use `meld` which is graphical and very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

[rmlint](https://rmlint.readthedocs.io/) has a feature for detecting duplicate directories:

```
-D --merge-directories (default: disabled)
```

From the man page:

*Makes *rmlint* use  a special mode where all found duplicates are collected and checked if whole directory trees are duplicates. Use with caution: You always should make sure that the  investigated directory is not modified during rmlint's or its removal scripts run.*

*IMPORTANT: Definition  of equal: Two directories are considered equal by rmlint if they contain the exact same data, no matter how the files containing the data are named. Imagine that  rmlint creates  a  long,  sorted  stream  out of the data found in the directory and compares this in a magic way to another directory. This means that the layout of the directory is not considered to be important by default. Also empty files will not count as content. This might be surprising to some users, but remember that rmlint generally cares only about content,  not  about  any  other metadata or layout. If you want to only find trees with the same hierarchy you should use --honour-dir-layout / -j.*

Comment: how do you run a dry run on, lets say `/tmp`?

Comment: Hey Rubo! Here's Ilario from LibreMesh, nice to see you here. Can you elaborate more on your question? I didn't get it, sorry.

Comment: This answer could use a working example how to use the command. By the time working I found out, that the rmlint tool doesn't actually delete anything, it just generates a script that you could execute to do the actual cleanup. So dry-run is not needed

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way around this problem would of course being *not having the problem in the first place*; what you seem to care about are immutable file sets, so instead of `cp -r original second`, you could just `ln -s original second`, and use the fact that Linux already allows you to "mirror" any folder or file into any other point in the file system hierarchy.

If you need the capabilities to change files in your second instance of your data, I'd recommend you use a refcounting file system (XFS, btrfs, a few others), and just ignore the fact that you have a copy – the files you didn't change in the copy don't use any extra space.

Now, assuming neither is an option:

Since you need to compare all directories to all directories (and luckily, that's cycle free, as long as you stay on one file system and don't follow symlinks), you'll need to do a duplicate subtree search on a tree. I don't think, no, I'm very sure, a shell script is not the environment you'd want to handle graph data structures in. That explodes very quickly – both in complexity for the shell as for you as human programmer.

So, sharpen your Rust, C++, Go, Erlang… and get coding:

You need to write a depth-first search algorithm that reproduces the directory structure, to prepare a representation of the directory tree in memory. Each node holds a value (e.g., a 64 bit integer) and whether it's been processed already; initially, none of the nodes are marked processed.

In that tree, you then take the leaf nodes, i.e. directories not containing other directories, and calculate a hash for the fileset within (in a stable, sorted manner, hash encompassing the things you care about – modification time, name, size, content?…); that hash becomes the value of the respective leaf node, and you mark the node as processed, and enter it into a hash map (use the node value as hash). If that value is already a key in the hash map – you check for actual identity (hash functions aren't a guarantee!), and delete the appropriate copy, and remove the corresponding node from the tree.

After you've marked all leaf nodes as processed (or even removed them from the tree), you go to the first parent node of the first leaf node, and hash the directory content, this time treating "marked processed" nodes as if regular files with their own appropriate hash. Through that, you get a value for that first parent node; you mark it as processed, add it to the hash table, delete if necessary, and move on to the next leaf node and do the same dance.
While you do that directory walk, you remove the leaf node and all siblings of the leaf node (they are only in one directory, and there can't be identical copies "higher up" in the tree, because that would imply a different depth of subdirectories within).

When done, the former "second-level from leaves" nodes have become leaf nodes: repeat until you've assigned a value to the root node.

Answer (score 0):

As an exercise, I implemented a duplicate directory finder in shell.

https://github.com/ilario/finddirdupes

It takes a first argument that is the folder to be analysed, and a second argument which is the minimum directory size to consider, in bytes. It is recommended to use at least 5000 for avoiding detecting many empty folders.

```
./finddirdupes.sh ~/documents 10000
```

Obviously, it is much slower than `rmlint -D` reported in another comment.

Answer (score -1):

This code does not check if the files content is identical, so you will have to check this yourself.

It compares folders based on the size and the subfolders and contained files' names.

Before running, check if the `-s` option of `ls -s` command works on your system.

```
# avoid starting with a non-empty dirhash file
rm dirhash

# while reads all the folders list provided by find (the <<< is a here string, passing the find output as an input to read)
# cd enters the folder
# ls lists the content, -1 on only one column, -a including the hidden files, -s indicating the files size (check if this works on your system), -R recursively entering every subdirectory
# xxhsum calculates a string from the output of ls
# the XXH3 hashing algorithm was the one suggested on
# https://xxhash.com/#benchmarks.
# du calculates the total size of the folder
while read d; do cd "$d"; hash=$(ls -1asR | xxhsum -H3); size=$(du -s); cd "$OLDPWD"; echo $hash $size $d >> dirhash; done <<< $(find ./ -type d)

# sort sorts the file based on the dir size, and then on the hash
# uniq shows all the duplicates based on the first 38 characters, which include the hash and the size from du
sort -k5n,5 -k4,4 dirhash | uniq --all-repeated=separate -w 38
```

Comment: very bad idea to hash `ls` output. It's not specified to be identical, and sorting order for recursive listing isn't stable, as far as I know.

Comment: Note that I think you're having a few differences between what you asked and what you answered, maybe fix your question to reflect that! Q: "How can I detect the duplicate folders, with the same content?" is a bit ambiguous; it seems to me A: "Here's how you detect duplicates ignoring the file contents" doesn't answer the same question!

Comment: I agree, the answer is not satisfactory, it does not check the files content. That's why I posted it here, hoping to receive a better alternative. The lack of ls output stability is not a problem, in my opinion, as you just compare hashes obtained at the same time on the same PC.